# Fast way to populate has_many through in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Suppose I have models Ant and Bats with a third join model Cats.  For each A I have a column containing the ids of all the Cs I want to join that row with. Currently I do the following:

```
Ant.all.each do |ant|
  ant.cat_ids.split(",").each do |id|
    ant.cats<<Bat.find(id)
  end
end
```

However this is pretty slow.  Anyone know of a faster way?

Comment: What DB are you using? Is the performance the first priority here?

Comment: postgresql; and yes performance is the first priority

Comment: In case of PostgreSQL try with `regexp_split_to_array` or `regexp_split_to_table`. You can INSERT ... SELECT ... and database will do all dirty work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting using direct sql is the fastest way to do this

```
ant_cat_ids = []
Ant.all.each do |ant|
  ant_cat_ids += ant.cat_ids.split(",").collect{|cat_id| "(#{ant.id}, #{cat_id})"}
end
Ant.connection.execute("INSERT INTO cats(ant_id, cat_id) VALUES #{ant_cat_ids.join(", ")}")
```

Answer (score 0):

A little better:

```
Ant.all.each do |ant|
  ant.cats << Bat.find(ant.cat_ids)
end
```